# Plant identification: low growing bushes

Tags: identification, shrubs, landscaping

[I'm on a learning mission to figure out what are growing around my house.] We have actually removed these bushes, as they were grown too close to house and seemed to hide roaches and mice.

[image: Unknown bushes]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Junipers; there are several varities sold for landscaping .

Comment: Now searching for junipers, I found this (https://www.homedepot.com/p/National-Plant-Network-2-25-Gal-Juniper-Procumbens-Nana-Shrub-HD7163/312284980) which looks like what we had. But when I did image search I only found these kinds of junipers (https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/shrubs/juniper/growing-creeping-junipers.htm)

Comment: It's most likely a cultivar of Juniperus horizontalis.